# How Can I comapre Two excel sheet using C# With the help of VBA code that I have below?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim LastRow_1 as Integer
Dim LastCol_1 as Integer
Dim Data_1 as Range
Dim LastRow_2 as Integer
Dim LastCol_2 as Integer
Dim Data_2 as Range

Dim Sh_1 as Worksheet
Dim Sh_2 as Worksheet

Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long
Dim C_1 as Range
Dim C_2 as Range

Set Sh_1  = Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Sh_2  = Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

LastRow_1 = Sh_1.Range("A65535").End(xlup).Row
LastCol_1 = Sh_1.Range("IV1").End(xltoLeft).Column
Set Data_1 = Sh_1.range("A1").Resize(LastRow_1,LastCol_1)

LastRow_2 = Sh_2.Range("A65535").End(xlup).Row
LastCol_2 = Sh_2.Range("IV1").End(xltoLeft).Column
Set Data_2 = Sh_2.range("A1").Resize(LastRow_2,LastCol_2)

For Each C_1 in Data_1
   For Each C_2 In Data_2
       If C_2 = C_1 then
         'found a cell on sheet2 that matched cell in sheet1
         'now do what you need to do
       End if
   Next C_2
Next C_1
```

Comment: What is the goal of you function?

Answer (score 1):

select the content of the worksheet to a datatable and you may use the DataRelations object to compare the two data tables.
You may also use merging of the two data tables to identify the differences.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
app.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbooks workbooks = m_app.Workbooks;
Excel.Workbook workbook = workbooks.Open(fileName);
workbook.Activate();
Excel.Sheets sheets = workbook.Sheets;
Excel.Worksheet sheet = sheets(1);
Excel.Range range = sheet.UsedRange;

// values will be an multi dimensional array of objects
object values = range.Value;

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheets);
workbook.Close(false);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
workbooks.Close();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
app.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
```

That'll read in one sheet, then just call the same code for the other sheet and then you can compare values as:

```
AreEqual(values(1,1), values2(1, 1));
```

Where `AreEqual` is a method you write that compares things properly accounting for nulls and datatypes etc.

Btw, I wrote the code above as C# as that what's said in the question title, but I see that the tag is VB.Net but if you want it as VB.Net just use some converter to convert it automatically, like http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ or similar.